# differential amplifier measuring current below supply rail

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, differential-amplifier

I am measuring the current from a battery (12v) using a shunt resistor. But if i can i want to use the normal rail  as supply for the op-amp:

[image: differential current measurement circuit]

Now my thinking is that because of the two voltage-dividers (r311/r314 and r312/r315), my non-inverting input will be closer to 1.8v than to 0, and my inverting input will 'start off' at 0v and then be pulled to ~1.8v by the op-amp.

Is this possible, or am i forgetting something? I didn't find any reading on this anywhere.

Comment: If you are unsure get yourself a free sim tool like LTSpice.

Comment: I did that, and it seems to work, but i did have my gain-setting back to front. so it seems to be that pulling the lower voltage level up, goes at the cost of the gain